# VBA - Setting counter in loop to copy/paste to next column in master sheet

Tags: excel, vba, loops

apologies as this might not be the most technical question.

I have been experimenting with this code to try and copy and paste a specified range ("de:e130") into a column in a master sheet and for each subsequent file to copy and paste into the next column. i have managed to get the below which seems to open up and files and pastes only into the one column as opposed to pasting in a subsequent column. I think a loop needs to be integrated in the structure to tell the copy/paste to paste into the next subsequent column in the master sheet.

Kind of stuck , any help would be greatly appreciated. current code below

```
Sub LoopThroughFolder()

    Dim MyFile As String, Str As String, MyDir As String, Wb As Workbook
    Dim Rws As Long, Rng As Range
    Dim a As Integer
    Set Wb = ThisWorkbook


    MyDir = "L:\Research\Research project\potato\"
    MyFile = Dir(MyDir & "*.xlsx")
    ChDir MyDir
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False



    Do While MyFile <> ""

        Workbooks.Open (MyFile), UpdateLinks:=False

        With Worksheets("Sheet Guidelines")

            Rws = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            Set Rng = Range("D1:E130")

            Rng.Copy Wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 1)

            ActiveWorkbook.Close True
        End With
        MyFile = Dir()
    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Sub LoopThroughFolder()
    Dim MyFile As String, Str As String, MyDir As String, Wb As Workbook, Wbtmp As Workbook, Sh As Worksheet
    Dim Rws As Long, Rng As Range
    Dim a As Integer, Clcnt As Long
    Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
    Clcnt = 1

    MyDir = "L:\Research\Research project\potato\"
    MyFile = Dir(MyDir & "*.xlsx")
    ChDir MyDir

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Do While MyFile <> ""
        Set Wbtmp = Workbooks.Open(MyFile, True)
        For Each Sh In Wbtmp.Sheets
            If Sh.Name = "Sheet Guidelines" Then
                Sh.Range("D1:E130").Copy Wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, Clcnt)
                Clcnt = Clcnt + 2
            End If
        Next Sh
        Wbtmp.Saved = True 'Assuming you DONT want to save the temporary workbook (no change to it so no point saving ?
        Wbtmp.Close
        MyFile = Dir()
    Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'If you turn the screenupdating off, you want to turn it back on at some point
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks O.PAL, on executing this code it gives me a subscript out of range error landing on the line Wbtmp.Sheets("Sheet Guidelines").Range("D1:E130").Copy Wb.Sheets("Sheets1").Cells(1, Clcnt)

Comment: Sorry, my bad for not testing it. See edit for tested version. It appears the error handler was no help for that case and the ChDir is actually helpfull.